# Swift `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.sssZ` string to date

Tags: ios, swift

I'm formatting a date string to date object using below code. But for some date strings it works and for some it returns nil.

Format = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.sssZ"

"2019-04-02T09:47:24.055Z" Works

"2019-03-27T22:31:17.140Z" Doesn't work

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.sssZ"


let date = dateFormatter.date(from: "2019-03-27T22:31:17.140Z")
```

Comment: Look at your date format. The format specifier for seconds and fractional seconds cannot be the same

Comment: As per @vadian suggestion you need to change your formate from `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.sssZ` to `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your format is wrong. It should be:

`"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"`

Have a look at date time format here:
https://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns

Answer (score 2):

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
        dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"


        let date = dateFormatter.date(from: "2019-04-02T09:47:24.055Z")
        let date1 = dateFormatter.date(from: "2019-03-27T22:31:17.140Z")
        print(">>>>>!!", date, date1)
```

> Optional(2019-04-02 09:47:24 +0000) Optional(2019-03-27 22:31:17 +0000)

The code above works as expected.

use `SSS` instead of `sss`

for your case of 
`yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.sssZ` and `2019-04-02T09:47:24.055Z`
output was :

> Optional(2019-04-02 09:47:55 +0000) nil

look at minutes and seconds:)

Comment: Thanks.It worked :-)