# How to know Date format getting from sever

Tags: ios, swift, date, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am trying to get date format of a date that I am getting from server.

What will be the format of this date:

```
2021-10-14T17:53:03.753588+05:30
```

What I tried:

```
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX
```

But Its not working.

Comment: Write your format above the date string you have. Add "spaces" if needed to make match each characters with its value: yyyy with "2021" etc, and you'll see what's wrong... Then see http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns to see what to add.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55492013/swift-yyyy-mm-ddthhmmss-sssz-string-to-date ?

Comment: Thanks @Larme for the link. Its working nice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How to (my tips & steps):

When you are struggling to find the date format for `String` -> `Date` ask you this: What my format is really doing? What's it's parsing/interpreting? Just let's see with `Date` -> `String`...

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX"
print(formatter.string(from: Date()))
```

Output: `2021-10-14T13:06:38+02:00`: Is it the "same" as the string we have? No, some are the same, but not all...

Let's continue with another tip:

Let's put our format and the string one above the other one:

```
2021-10-14T17:53:03.753588+05:30
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX
```

Then, let's add "spaces", to make each pattern match its corresponding input:

```
2021-10-14  T  17:53:03.753588 +05:30
yyyy-MM-dd 'T' HH:mm:ss          XXX
```

Then, let's check the [doc](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns) (it's bookmarked in my web browser) for interpretation of the pattern and check if they correspond if needed, and to find the missing one if needed too.

Ok, so we aren't interpreting `.753588` at all, that's why it's failing...
It's for the fractional seconds, so if we change the format to: `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX"`, it should work. Note, you can replace `XXX` with `Z` if you want...

Now, remember that patterns are case sensitive, so if you have strange hours, minutes, or nil because of that, check if you didn't misuse minutes vs month, 12h format vs 24 hour format...
If you have hours diff (or usually 30min diff), the issue could be then a timezone issue.
If you have a day diff, it could also be a timezone issue (interpret it as hours diffs around midnight, so there is a day change).
If you have a year diff, check if you didn't misuse `yyyy` vs `YYYY`.

Etc. But that should cover most of your cases (basic issues).

Answer (score 0):

Try this format.
"***yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSXXX***"

As the date format you mentioned in your question contains milliseconds as well as timezone offset info.

Once date is parsed then based on your need you can set output date format and will get formatted date.

```
let sampleDate = "2021-10-14T17:53:03.753588+05:30" 
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter() dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSXXX" // Set input date format. 
let inputDate = dateFormatter.date(from: sampleDate) 

print("Input Date:- \(inputDate)")

dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss" // Set output date format as per need 
let outputDate = dateFormatter.string(from: inputDate ?? Date())         

print("Output Date:- \(outputDate)")
```